# Width of element not correctly rendered via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the width of the element `main` in my HTML page via jQuery. I'm absolutely not an expert in jQuery and I don't even really know the difference between JavaScript and jQuery, so don't shoot me. I believe I need this to be done in jQuery.

I've written a function that calculates the width of this element. I'm running it when the document is loaded ánd when the document is resized. When I resize the page, it renders correctly. But on when it loads, it's not correct.

This is because I have a menu that extends when the windows is bigger than 1200px.

I currently have this jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

function articleResize() {
    if ( $("main").width() > 1200 ) {
        $("#artikel-met-sidebar").addClass('col-l-8');
    } else {
        $("#artikel-met-sidebar").removeClass('col-l-8');
    }

    var p = $( "main" );
    $( "#artikel-met-sidebar-sidebar" ).text(
      "outerWidth():" + $("main").outerWidth() +
      " , width():" + $("main").width() );
}

$(document).ready(articleResize);
window.onload = articleResize;
window.onresize = articleResize;
```

I've tried a lot that is not working...

Comment: I'm not looking for an element with the class `main`, but for the tag `<main>`

Comment: Add a fiddle (code that can be executed) with HTML and all.

Answer (score 0):

Why there are two `$(document).ready?`? Don't do that unless you mean it.

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function articleResize() {
        if ( $("main").width() > 1200 ) {
            $("#artikel-met-sidebar").addClass('col-l-8');
        } else {
            $("#artikel-met-sidebar").removeClass('col-l-8');
        }

        var p = $( "main" );
        $( "#artikel-met-sidebar-sidebar" ).text(
          "outerWidth():" + $("main").outerWidth() +
          " , width():" + $("main").width() );
    }
    window.onresize = articleResize;
    articleResize();
}
```

Note that when the document is "ready", the "window.onload" event will not be fired!

Comment: This does not make a difference, it's still not correct.

Comment: Why? I've tried similar code in my own website, it worked. @Stef